# SharePoint Email Functionlity -Javascript

Tags: email

I have a piece of code, used to send mail using SharePoint Mail utility function, which is working fine.

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: urlTemplate,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'properties': {
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
            },
            'From': from,
            'To': {
                'results': [to]
            },
            'Body': body,
            'Subject': subject
        }
    }),
```

I just want to know how can I send same with CCing some one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add to your properties.

```
'CC': {
      'results': [CC]
    },
```

I hope it helps.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246781.aspx)

Comment: I want to send email to multiple users in CC. How can i do that?

Comment: [CC] is a string array. Use like this 'results':["ccuser1@email.com","ccuser2@email.com"]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246895.aspx), there is a `CC` property you can use for this. Should be able to just add the additional property and set the value the same way you do for `to`.